# Maven common parent with custom reporting plugin configuration

Tags: maven, module, maven-release-plugin

My team has a common parent project with a module containing several reporting plugin configurations (e.g. checkstyle and findbugs, similar to [Checkstyle's multimodule configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html), but in a separate project).  I'm going to call the common parent project "common" and the reporting module "build-tools".

I'm trying to find a way to, when the common project is released, to have the common project reference the correct version of the build-tools module without doing a manual release.

Here are a couple of the things I've tried:

- Use ${project.version} for the build-tools version number.  This uses the version number specified in the projects using the common as a parent.
- Use regular version numbers.  These are not updated in the common project.
- Use a property.  Again, the property value isn't updated on release.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I don't fully understand your problem. If common aggregates build-tools, why would common refer to a version of build-tools? Is common the parent of build-tools or only the parent of some other unnamed module(s)?

Comment: @Ryan common is a parent pom for every other project our team has and an aggregator pom which has build-tools as a module.  build-tools does not have common as a parent.  common also references build-tools as a plug-in dependency for several plugins.  My issue is that I can't find an automated way to keep the build-tools dependency in common up to date.

Comment: Did some scanning through the issue tracker and it looks like http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-649 is related to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the maven-release-plugin are you using? Try 2.1. That should properly handle the replacement of version properties.

Comment: I'm using 2.1 right now.  Now that I think about it, part of the issue may be that the only place the version is referenced is as a plugin dependency.  Using the property in dependency management may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is to make common and build-tools the same version and use -DautoVersionSubmodules when you release:prepare. Since common aggregates build-tools, if both modules have the same SNAPSHOT version when you do a release, the release plugin will release and uprev both of them.

**Edit:** To keep the dependency version correct, your first option should work. In common:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

That will make your common project always have a dependency on build-tools with the same version as common itself. If they always uprev in lock-step, that should do what you want. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Updated my answer. Haven't you already tried that way though?

Comment: I don't have it as a direct dependency, it's a plugin dependency, which is why, based on what I saw at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-649, why I think it's not working - it's not going through *all* of the dependencies, just the direct ones (dependencyManagement and dependencies).

Comment: Have you looked into [plugin management](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)?